# How to use knockout "onEnter" with $(document).on("keypress", "form"

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just want to know how to use knockout's `onEnter` with jQuery's `$(document).on("keypress", "form"...`

Because each time I press enter in a `form`it will submit the formular to the server.

Using `event.preventDefault()` will prevent the submitting the form, but that also prevents knockouts `onEnter`... ?!

```
$(document).on("keypress", "form", function (event)
{
    if ($(event.target).closest("input[data-bind*='onEnter']")[0])
    {
         event.preventDefault(); //preventing form to be submitted
         return true;//but the function behind 'onEnter' will not be trigered
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 13)//Enter
    {
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
    }
});
```

How will `onEnter` be triggered after the code mentioned above ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using JQuery to handle the keypress rather than using `data-bind="submit: doSomething"` on your `<form>` ? (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html) And by having a type "submit" button in your form the enter button will act as expected

Comment: @Darren Actually I have no event handler and no button which will cause that submit(it is moreover a standard behavior of html to send a formular when pressing enter), don't ask me the reason for using the `form`-container without an action(someone made that decision, maybe because of bootstrap3 ...).
The form looks like this `<form class="..." id="..." role="form" >`

Comment: Ok, so you have no button in your form but the expected behavior would be to press enter? How would the user know this? (just curious) - and you're also perhaps wise to take a look at creating your own binding handler rather that trying to mix jquery with knockout. I'll add an answer..

Comment: @Darren the user incteraction with the server happens over different buttons/events... I think the "other" just took bootstrap's standard example to create a certain look  and at that time they did not thought of knockouts `onEnter` and html standard behavior of sending a form when pressing enter. And here we are at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you're going to use JQuery you will need to keep it within the context of Knockout otherwise you're going to have major issues in your bindings and having your view update when things change. Also, you in your current code you would have to call your viewmodel.yourMethod - this isn't ideal.

That being said, it would be worth creating your own `bindingHandler` to handle this and then add the handler to whatever element you're after.

This hasn't been tested, though will get you somewhere near.

```
// the custom binding handler, its called executeOnEnter
ko.bindingHandlers.executeOnEnter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        // in this case, element is the html element you bound the handler - so perhaps your form tag
        $(element).keypress(function (event) {
            var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
            // the enter key
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                allBindings.executeOnEnter.call(viewModel);
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
};
```

You can then attach this to your form, something like:

`<form data-bind="executeOnEnter:theFunctionInYourViewModelToCall" >`

Comment: Like i said - its untested. It actually came from one of the environments we built so works here. I cannot comment on how you have built out your viewmodel. The point is, this is the direction you would be better going as you can use this code (once fixed for you) to work on any enter button for any viewmodel, rather than a method directly in your viewmodel

Comment: I cannot help you in your precise environment. I cannot debug your code. Only you can do that. I have provided you with some tooling and some idea. The error actually says "call" is undefined, in that it doesn't exist on allBindings.executeOnEnter - The rest of the implementation and any debugging is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You must let Knockout do all the top-level event handling in your application.

There is the the built-in `submit` binding that captures the `submit` event of a form:

```
<form data-bind="submit: captureEnter"></textarea>
```

It works the same with the built-in `event` binding for all kinds of other events:

```
<textarea data-bind="event: {keypress: captureEnter}"></textarea>
```

In the `captureEnter` method in your viewmodel you can look into the key code and react to the Enter key:

```
self.captureEnter = function (vm, event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

    if (keyCode === 13) {
        // do something...
    } else {
        return true; // let the event do what it normally would do
    }
});
```

By default, [Knockout prevents the default action of an event](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-action). Use `return true;` to allow the default action (i.e. "form is submitted" or "character appears in text area" etc).